# How do I redirect to a different domain AND a different folder?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect

What htaccess rule would I need to apply to redirect to a different domain but also to a different folder structure? Example: current page is

```
http://oldwebsite.com/school/forum
```

and the new website would be

```
https://newwebsite.com/forum
```

I figured that the rewrite rule for the domain name alone would be

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

which works just fine when I test it.
But I can't find out what rule I'd need for rewriting the old forum posts that are in an unnecessary subfolder to the new domain where it's directly in /forum.

Also: would I need to write http**s** or is that something that doesn't matter and will be done automatically if I have an SSL certificate and the forum (phpbb3 in this case) is set to SSL anyway?

Thanks and best regards,
Andi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for I assume:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?school/(.*)$ https://newwebsite.com/$1 [R=301]
```

That rule will work in the http servers host configuration and likewise in a dynamic configuration file (`.htaccess`) then the hosts document root. Obviously the rewriting module must be enabled. If you decide to use a dynamic configuration file, then you additionally need to allow that using the `AllowOverride` directive.

You need to specify the `https` protocol, since that is where the redirected client will make the connection to. That is something the client has to decide *before* having contact with the server. So whether a ssl certificate is installed does not really help in that. You *mighty* rely on an additional redirection from http to http on the new domain, but why? Much better to redirect directly to the ssl port in the first place.

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the rule seems to work! And I suppose the order of the two rules is important as well, right?
I tested it on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and if I have the
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L] above yours, yours doesn't work.
Yours on top though and mine below seems to work for all the cases then. Whether it is a normal url for the main site or one for the forum in the subdirectory.

Comment: Certainly the order of the rules is important. They are simply processes from top to bottom. First match get's applied. In case of an external redirection that's it locally, no more rule get's even evaluated. So as a rule of thumb you first place specific rules, then more general ones. And exceptional rules like the one discussed here should be on top. No sense in evaluating other rules first, is there?